# Strange behaviour gtools:mixedorder combined with dplyr::arrange?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I noticed an unexpected outcome while using `dplyr::arrange` together with `gtools::mixedorder`.

Consider:

```
library(tidyverse)

test <- data.frame(V1 = c("all13_LG1", "all13_LG10", "all13_LG11",
 "all13_LG12", "all13_LG13", "all13_LG14", "all13_LG15", "all13_LG16",
 "all13_LG2", "all13_LG3", "all13_LG4", "all13_LG5", "all13_LG6",
 "all13_LG7", "all13_LG8", "all13_LG9"),
 V2 = c(rep(1:16)))

test2 <- test %>% arrange(gtools::mixedorder(V1))

test3 <- test %>% slice(gtools::mixedorder(V1))
```

In test2 the 1st column is sorted: `"all13_LG1", "all13_LG3", "all13_LG4", "all13_LG5", "all13_LG6", "all13_LG7", "all13_LG8", "all13_LG9", "all13_LG10", "all13_LG11", "all13_LG12", "all13_LG13", "all13_LG14", "all13_LG15", "all13_LG16", "all13_LG2"`

Whereas in test3, the columns are sorted as one would expect when using gtools:mixedorder

Why is this happening when I combine arrange and mixedtools? Is this a bug?

Many thanks,
Anneke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use results of `mixedorder` in `arrange` you need to `order` the results.

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% arrange(order(gtools::mixedorder(V1)))

#           V1 V2
#1   all13_LG1  1
#2   all13_LG2  9
#3   all13_LG3 10
#4   all13_LG4 11
#5   all13_LG5 12
#6   all13_LG6 13
#7   all13_LG7 14
#8   all13_LG8 15
#9   all13_LG9 16
#10 all13_LG10  2
#11 all13_LG11  3
#12 all13_LG12  4
#13 all13_LG13  5
#14 all13_LG14  6
#15 all13_LG15  7
#16 all13_LG16  8
```

Comment: Interesting! Do you know why this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

We can `slice` with `mixedsort` and `match`

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
   slice(match(gtools::mixedsort(V1), V1))
```

-output

```
           V1 V2
1   all13_LG1  1
2   all13_LG2  9
3   all13_LG3 10
4   all13_LG4 11
5   all13_LG5 12
6   all13_LG6 13
7   all13_LG7 14
8   all13_LG8 15
9   all13_LG9 16
10 all13_LG10  2
11 all13_LG11  3
12 all13_LG12  4
13 all13_LG13  5
14 all13_LG14  6
15 all13_LG15  7
16 all13_LG16  8
```